# ipython Pandas : why I cannot print the legend for matplot graphs?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using this code to put legend on my graph but it is not possible.

```
   for key in ['cluster0', 'cluster1', 'cluster2', 'cluster3']:
        mask = e['cluster'] == key
        ax.scatter(e['count_sbwip'][mask],e['perc_of_seen_ip'][mask],
                           c=LABEL_COLOR_MAP[key],  label=LABEL_NAMES_MAP[key])
    ax.legend()
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's just a typo. As the traceback shows, you were calling `ax.scatter` with the argument `lebel` instead of `label`.
2. If you want four legends on the same plot, you can simply call `ax.scatter` 4 times with the corresponding `label` argument. I suppose it is possible create this legend by hand, but it's probably more complex then using something like,

   ```
   for key in ['cluster0', 'cluster1', 'cluster2', 'cluster3']:
       mask = e['cluster'] == key
       ax.scatter(e['count_sbwip'][mask],e['perc_of_seen_ip'][mask],
                          c=LABEL_COLOR_MAP[key],  label=LABEL_NAMES_MAP[key])
   ax.legend()
   ```

Comment: Thanks rth. indeed was my mistake. But It did not work, I have edited the question